# Can I have a subclass of my class as property in Swift?

Tags: swift

In **Swift 2.1** I need to [initialize](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) every properties before use the class method. But if I want to have a property that is a subclass of it, I will have an infinite loop. Is this possible?

```
class Myclass {
    let mySubClass:SubClass
    init() {
        mySubClass = SubClass()
        print("Init my class")
    }
}

class SubClass:Myclass {
    override init() {
        print("Init subclass")
    }
}

let myClass = Myclass()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a lazy stored property.

The instance of the subclass isn't initialized until it's used the first time.

```
class Myclass {
  lazy var mySubClass : SubClass = {
    return SubClass()
  }()

  init() {
    print("Init my class")
  }
}

class SubClass:Myclass {
  override init() {
    print("Init subclass")
  }
}

let myClass = Myclass()
myClass.mySubClass
```

Comment: Great, this is the answer. A lazy  with closures. I have tried the lazy, but not in this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off to be explicit about the relationships.  Something like:

```
class Myclass {
    var mySubClass:SubClass?
    init() {
        print("Init my class")
    }
}

class SubClass:Myclass {
    override init() {
        print("Init subclass")
    }
}

var myClass = Myclass()
let mySub = SubClass()
myClass.mySubClass = mySub
```

Comment: Lol, good answer. This solve the problem. But I was curious now, isn't any way to do it in class itself? Because it is external to the class. I was thinking that was because of problem like this that in Objective-C we need to do the [[alloc] init]. But in Swift we only use one phase.  So I can't do that in a invisible way to the user of the class?